# Insert HTML Page in WordPress Page

Tags: html

I Know this may be the repetitive question, But whatever solutions are given, nothing is helping me..

I have created the page

```
http://creditsmart.in/wp-content/themes/voice/emicalc.html
```

I want to add this page to my WordPress Page Only..

1) I have tried 'text' mode using iframe. Nothing happened..
2) I have directly put my html in WordPress page.. Nothing happened..
3) Also, Whatever css and JS the above (emicalc.html) page is referencing to, I have put the same reference to header.php also. and then i tried to put  tag in the Wordpress page.. Still Nothing happened..

I dont want to use any plugin. Please

Video shared for better understanding of problem - `http://tinypic.com/r/2d93709/9`

Any help shall be highly appreciated

Comment: What about a shortcode?

Comment: @jgraup - I dont want to use any plugin. Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because it's a non-secure page `http` but you're loading into an `https` page. It's called [`Mixed Content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content).

---

Adjust your protocol to `//` and hope it renders over `https`.

```
<iframe src="//creditsmart.in/wp-content/themes/voice/emicalc.html" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "300px" width = "100%">
</iframe>
```

( iframe code modified from @Ittikorn's answer )

---

If the file is in your same theme directory it's possible to create a shortcode:

```
[emicalc]
```

Then render the local file:

```
function emicalc__shortcode( $atts ) {

    $content = file_get_contents( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/emicalc.html');
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode( 'emicalc', 'emicalc__shortcode' );
```

If it's remote you might be able to use [`wp_remote_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) instead of [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) but it requires you pull the contents using the server instead of allowing the client to do it.

---

There is no other trick / `https` can only load `https` / `http` can always load `https`.

Comment: Oh You have taken it correctly,  then, how should i proceed further then ??

Answer (score 1):

I tried to insert this `iframe` code into the text mode and it seems to be working. You can adjust the height value if it does not fit, but try to leave the width value at 100%.

```
<iframe src="//creditsmart.in/wp-content/themes/voice/emicalc.html" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "300px" width = "100%">
</iframe>
```

Comment: @lttikorn - I have done the same what you have said, Still the same problem exist. Please find the attached link for video sharing for better understanding..http://tinypic.com/r/2d93709/9

Comment: @user2921939, Sumit has corrected the protocal issue by removing the http in front of the url. Can you try again and see whether it solves your problem or not?

Comment: yes, how can i render the same on https ??